# Where can I learn how to combine algorithms and data structures?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

After reading an introductory book on algorithms and data structures I am now craving for examples on how to combine these for optimal efficiency.

For instance, you can combine hashmaps with specific sorting algorithms to create a simple text search program.

Is there any good book or online resource for this?

(I have already ordered [Programming Pearls](http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/), which looks great, but I want to learn *more* about this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any good algorithms book is going to have a chapter or two on the importance of choosing the right data structures.  I recommend the following books:

- [Algorithms in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059651624X)
- [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)
- [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600)

I also recommend you check out the [Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/), particularly the [lectures](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/video-lectures/).

Answer (score 4):

Go to these websites and try out the problems:

1. [acm.uva.es](http://acm.uva.es)
2. [topcoder.com/tc](http://topcoder.com/tc)
3. [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/)
4. [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/)

They have problems to satisfy you for at least the next 3-4 years.

Answer (score 2):

Good book (worked for me):

[Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java (Second Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201357542)

Published by Addison-Wesley, 2007

ISBN: 0-321-37013-9

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking for what a programmer does all day: Flow data through certain algorithms in such a way that you get the result you want in a timely manner. I suggest that you download [Python](http://www.python.org/) and work through the tutorials. Python allows you to test your ideas very quickly.

Comment: I've been programming in python for a couple of years already. :) What I am looking for is more the most _efficient_ ways of doing things.  Think interview questions, albeit in a more general sense.

Comment: With any but the most simple problems, there is always more than one "best" solution. Some run faster, some need less memory, other are easier to maintain, some need the least amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it seems I just have to read up on a lot of algorithms and real world use cases.

As for books, I've ordered

- [Programming Pearls](http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) to read about how one solves real world problems using a combination of algorithms.
- [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) by [Steven Skiena](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/), which contains a catalogue of alrogithms and *war stories* on how real world problems were solved.

Comment: Both are excellent choices.  Enjoy.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Structure-Interpretation-Computer-Programs-Second/dp/0070004846/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301994609&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070004846)

I can warmly recommend this book. It is rather abstract with examples in Scheme (a Lisp dialect) but it will really change the way you think about programs, data and algorithms.